# How does $facet works?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using $facet, it works fine with my mlab, but when I connect to azure cosmos DB it says

`{"error":{"ok":0,"errmsg":"Unrecognized pipeline stage name: $facet","code":40324,"codeName":"40324","name":"MongoError"}}`

I am using below query

````
collection.aggregate([{
        $match: "test"
    },
    {
        $facet: {
            metadata: [{
                    $count: "total"
                }

            ],
            data: [{
                    $project: {

                        fieldname: 1,


                    }
                }

            ]

        }
    }

])```
````

Comment: It's not supported [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#w144aac17c19b5b3)

Comment: @Valijon my query is about AZURE, while this doc is for AWS. What could be possible alternate of this query?

Comment: Sry, wrong link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36#aggregation-stages)

Comment: `What could be possible alternate of this query?`: We need to see what are you trying to do. Share sample data, full query, expected result, etc..

Comment: Its a simple collection, all I need total result count of paginationat "tatal" key, but it is showing total of current result count,

datacollection.aggregate([
        { $match: queryString },
        { $skip: toSkip },
        { $limit: resultLimit },
        { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$corrId",
                total: { "$sum": 1 }, 
                "data": { $push: "$$ROOT" }
            }
        }
    ])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per below documented links, AZURE and AWS do not support $facet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36#aggregation-stages

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#w144aac17c19b5b3